# Snowflake Conditions in Window Function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, relational-database, window-functions

I am trying to write a window function to help me retrieve a single field from a second table that I need to join to my existing table. The issue is the only way to figure out which value out of many possible values is the correct one requires matching two IDs and then out of those options (options where IDs match) pulling the most recent one that is not before a date (which is different for each record and pulled from the initial table).

Right now I have written:

```
Select distinct primary_id,
       first_value(desired_column) over partition by id_1, id_2, order by date desc)
From base_table
Left join second_table 
on second_table.id_1 = base_table.id_1 and 
   second_table.date <= base_table.date
```

However, this is still returning incorrect values. The returned table should have the same row count as base_table, but with the desired_column added based on whichever record matches ids but also happens before the base_table date (each desired_column value should be one result, the most recent one before the base_table date that matches the ids). This has the same row count, but it's returning desired_column values that are completely incorrect (I suspect that it is because I don't break down the second date <= base in the window function directly, but that isn't possible? I'm not sure how to proceed.)

Thank you in advance.

Edit to add:

Sample Base Table

| Primary Key | ID1 | ID2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 321 | 01/22/2021 |
| 2 | 123 | 654 | 09/02/2022 |
| 3 | 234 | 432 | 02/02/2019 |

Sample Second Table

| Desired_Column | ID1 | ID2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| q | 123 | 321 | 01/21/2021 |
| r | 123 | 654 | 09/03/2022 |
| w | 234 | 432 | 02/01/2019 |
| s | 234 | 432 | 03/20/2022 |
| a | 123 | 439 | 02/20/2022 |
| w | 999 | 999 | 09/10/2022 |
| null | 234 | 987 | 10/10/2020 |

Desired Output

| Primary Key | ID1 | ID2 | Date | Desired_Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 321 | 01/22/2021 | q |
| 2 | 123 | 654 | 09/02/2022 | null |
| 3 | 234 | 432 | 02/02/2019 | w |

Comment: Sample data and desired results please

Answer (score 1):

so making some CTE's for the data:

```
with base_table(primary_id, ID_1, ID_2, Date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 123, 321, '01/22/2021'::date),
    (2, 123, 654, '09/02/2022'::date),
    (3, 234, 432, '02/02/2019'::date)
), second_table(Desired_Column, ID_1, ID_2, Date) as (
    select * from values
    ('q'    ,123, 321, '01/21/2021'::date),
    ('r'    ,123, 654, '09/03/2022'::date),
    ('w'    ,234, 432, '02/01/2019'::date),
    ('s'    ,234, 432, '03/20/2022'::date),
    ('a'    ,123, 439, '02/20/2022'::date),
    ('w'    ,999, 999, '09/10/2022'::date),
    (null   ,234, 987, '10/10/2020'::date)
)
```

and then correcting your SQL:

```
Select distinct b.primary_id,
       first_value(s.desired_column) over (partition by b.id_1, b.id_2 order by s.date desc)
From base_table as b
Left join second_table as s
on s.id_1 = b.id_1 and 
   s.date <= b.date
```

gives:

| PRIMARY_ID | FIRST_VALUE(S.DESIRED_COLUMN) OVER (PARTITION BY B.ID_1, B.ID_2 ORDER BY S.DATE DESC) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | q |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | w |

but the distinct is the hint, this is not the method you are looking for...

dropping the [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) which get a result for very row, and using a [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) to RANK the rows, just keep the best (aka 1)

```
Select b.primary_id,
       s.desired_column
From base_table as b
Left join second_table as s
on s.id_1 = b.id_1 and 
   s.date <= b.date
qualify row_number() over (partition by b.id_1, b.id_2 order by s.date desc) = 1
```

gives:

| PRIMARY_ID | DESIRED_COLUMN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | q |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | w |

but also allow accessing all the other values from the two tables:

```
Select b.*,
       s.*   
From base_table as b
Left join second_table as s
on s.id_1 = b.id_1 and 
   s.date <= b.date
qualify row_number() over (partition by b.id_1, b.id_2 order by s.date desc) = 1
```

And given you want to match "both ID's" you should use this SQL:

```
Select b.primary_id,
    b.id_1,
    b.id_2,
    s.desired_column 
From base_table as b
Left join second_table as s
on s.id_1 = b.id_1 and 
   s.id_2 = b.id_2 and 
   s.date <= b.date
qualify row_number() over (partition by b.id_1, b.id_2 order by s.date desc) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!! When I run this I get about half as many rows as I'm trying to get--I want the resulting table to have every value from the base table with all the filled in ones from desired_column.

Comment: to use the qualify method you will need to understand your data. One way to work around not understanding your own data, is to add a SEQ8() to all the base_data, before the join, and then put that into the row_number() and then not display it.